# Какое использовать событие при загрузке программы для "отрисовки" экрана?

Tags: java, android

В методе onCreate пытаюсь определить размеры компонента ImageView, основного лайяута. Программа сообщает, что они равны нулю (w=o,h=0).
Пробовал запихать в onStart(), результат тот же. 
Когда делаю определение размеров (ImageView) по нажатию кнопки все определяется правильно.
Размеры нужны для создания картинки в памяти и потом выводе в ImageView.
Необходимо, чтобы при загрузке программы она сама создавала картинку и размещала в ImageView без нажатия на кнопку (сейчас отрисовка работает, но по кнопке).

Comment: В onCreate разметка ещё не полностью подсчитала свои размеры. Способов это обойти несколько и они разной степени хардкорности. Попробуйте сначала в onResume размеры получать.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете установить у ImageView параметр                 `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

и тогда система сама отмасштабирует картинку, поместит её в центре, а лишнее обрежет

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivPhoto"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                tools:background="@drawable/dummy_photo"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                />
```

В наличии есть [8 видов масштабирования](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте что-то типо такого:

```
float scale = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;    
px = dp_that_you_want * (scale / 160);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams  = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(px, px);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Надеюсь, что это вам помогло.

Comment: Попробуй так ViewTreeObserver observer = imageView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        imageView.getHeight();
    }

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

ViewTreeObserver observer = imageView.getViewTreeObserver(); vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { @Override public void onGlobalLayout() { imageView.getHeight(); }